# How to check if there's no errors in authentication process in Firebase Web?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm new to Web Development, especially to Firebase.

I'm trying to check if there are no errors while creating a user in Firebase Authentication system, so I can put this user into Database.

Here's my code:

```
function register() {

    var firebaseRef = firebase.database().ref();

    var shaObj = new jsSHA("SHA-256", "TEXT")
    shaObj.update(passwordField.value)

    //console.log(hash)

    var email = emailField.value
    var password = shaObj.getHash("HEX")

    if (isBarber != null) {

        if (email != "" && password != "") {

            firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function(error) {
                $('#errorMsg').show();
                $('#errorMsg').text(error.message);

                if (error === null) {

                    var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
                    var userID = user.uid;

                    firebase.database().ref('users/' + userID).set({
                        userEmail: email,
                        userPassword: password,
                        userIsBarber: isBarber
                    })
                }
            });         
        } else {
            alert('Email or password fields are empty')
        }
    } else {
        alert('Select your role')
    }
}
```

`createUserWithEmailAndPassword` works properly and creates a user, but I don't know *how to check if there are no errors* so I could add this user to database.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `then()` to action on a successful registration as follows:

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(function(user) {
    //Registration is successful
    var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    var userID = user.uid;

    firebase.database().ref('users/' + userID).set({
        userEmail: email,
        userPassword: password,
        userIsBarber: isBarber
    })

}).catch(error) {
    //Registration unsuccessful 
    $('#errorMsg').show();
    $('#errorMsg').text(error.message);

});
```